# How to handle conversion of 32728 Hz for playback on common software/devices?

Tags: mp3, sample-rate, compatibility, encoding

I've been working on converting the soundtrack from a video game from its original format to something that you can easily play back on regular consumer devices. The system is Nintendo 3DS, utilizing 24ch 32728 Hz sampling rate.

I've made two versions: flac, and mp3. flac seems to be fine, but some software (notably iTunes) chokes on the mp3 because it was downscaled to 32000 Hz during conversion. It plays back the song, but there's significant distortions and cracks in the output. The mp3 files play back fine on other software such as Winamp, though. I'm using the lame encoder (`lame.exe -S --noreplaygain -V 0 - %d` at ~245 kbps VBR via foobar2000).

Sample files:

- [MP3 file at 32000 Hz](https://mega.co.nz/#!GgE1HKqa!JeJLKrBp3ce1d5jWSOKp-7M8N0wUOkW_wyR4U8YnK2U)
- [FLAC file at 32728 Hz](https://mega.co.nz/#!HxcjjYbL!vS5xJmTPnmGeMVEatf_8WBoaHHGScwSg2kzjm0rjxVk)

What's the recommended method for dealing with this? How do I get the mp3 files to play back properly?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is on-topic here or not.  It seems very consumer oriented in general.  It has some flavors of mastering to it, but I'm not really sure if it falls in to that category or not.  I'll leave it open for now and see what the community thinks, but it may or may not get a strong response here.

Comment: If you can recommend me a different Stack site to go to, I'd be happy to take my question there.

Comment: Although it appears from the question msikma is not doing sound design, but merely converting an existing source to another format, the issue described could happen in a sound design process too. This has to do with the delivery format of sounds, so it is about the last stage of sound design.

Answer (score 0):

You can just upsample them to a common sample rate, like 44100 Hz. Of course, you won't gain any audio quality, but a good upsampler won't reduce it either, even if it's not a round conversion.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Do you think lame_enc itself is "good enough" for upscaling to 44.1 kHz these days? (Also, I thought that 32 kHz was a common rate too.)

Comment: Lame doesn't do any scaling or processing at all save for the coding, it's just a codec, all of that is done in the mother-program, or a plugin for the same. Both Wavelab and Pro Tools has good upscalers. Others have too, but these I know for sure.